# How to list Google Plus Business for a particular google plus user?

Tags: php, google-plus, google-api-php-client

How to **list an authenticated user's google plus business pages** using the [google-api-php-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/?r=474) library?

So far, I can view the user personal information as well as feeds from the user's google plus page using the code page:

```
require_once 'gplus/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'gplus/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';
$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setClientId('xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('xxxxx');
$client->setRedirectUri('https://mywebsite.com/redirect');

$client->authenticate($code);
$token = $client->getAccessToken();

//Get only access token
$access_token_arr = json_decode($token);
$access_token = $access_token_arr->access_token;

//Get user info
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token='.$access_token;
$gplus_user = json_decode(file_get_contents($url)); //This gives me personal information about the user.
```